# Exe file remote Execution

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to write a script which will patch SQL Instances remotely. Referring this forum, I have framed the following line for executing the .exe remotely on other server:

```psh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
  & cmd /c 'D:\SQL_PATCH\SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU.exe'  /qs /action=patch /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
}
```

Also tried this as well:

```psh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
  & 'D:\SQL_PATCH\SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU.exe' -ArgumentList "/qs", "/action=patch", "/allinstances", "/IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms"
}
```

One more peculiar thing with this is, the first command is running fine on the Windows 2012 servers but not on Windows 2008R2 server. I don't know what's the reason behind this.

Comment: Try ths `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {D:\SQL_PATCH\SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU.exe /qs /action=patch /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms}`  You need to also make sure that A) the remote computer has PowerShell Remoting enabled B) your current PowerShell session is running as admin and C) you must have admin privs on the remote computer.  If you don't have admin privs, then you need to provide credentials that do.

Comment: @KeithHill: The command that you gave is not working. Also whatever parameters that you said, all were checked before I started making this script. Kindly suggest any other alternative. thanks

Comment: replace `/qs` with `/q` . Also does the setup writes a log file on the remote server? There's is a specific location for SQL-Server setup logs.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf: This edit is also not working. Also i don't anything in the setup bootstrap folder. No files are getting generated. Thanks for ur comment

Comment: What happens if you execute command on a failing server manually by entering PS Session: `etsn $computer; cd d:\sql_patch; .\SQLServer2012SP2....exe ... /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms` ?

Comment: @majkinetor: When I execute `D:\SQL_PATCH\SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU.exe /qs /action=patch /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms` this on the server locally, it installs properly which can be verified from Add or remove programs in control panel. Do you want me to execute the command given by you in place of the current **Invoke-Command**

Comment: @Lilly123, not locally, that is irrelevant. You have to execute it on the failing system. Just `Enter-Session` like I said (alias `etsn`), do not use invoke.

Comment: @majkinetor: I tried your edit, but now I'm getting an error saying **D:\SQL_PATCH path does not exists**. This error didn't show when i tried the above invoke commands. Also, this path is vaild on the server as well. kindly look into this

Comment: @Lilly123, I highly doubt that it exists. Perhaps it is named differently. Do `ls *sql*` and see its real name. Perhaps its on different drive etc.

Comment: @majkinetor: That's the thing. It does exists. if i execute this `D:\SQL_PATCH\SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU.exe /qs /action=patch /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms` locally, the results are perfect. Also a certain change `cd \\$computer\d$\sql_patch;` in your script is making it run without any erros. But still I don't see anything getting updated either in Logs or Control panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following did the trick to what I was looking for:

```
psexec \\$computer -s -u Adminuser -p AdminPassword E:\SQL_PATCH\SQLServer2012SP2-KB2958429-x64-ENU.exe /quiet /action=patch /allinstances /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms
```

This piece is working on all the servers irrespective for Windows versions.
Thanks everyone for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: When you ran Invoke-Command were you logged in as Adminuser?  If not, then should have used the `-Credential` parameter on Invoke-Command to pass in the Adminuser credentials.

Comment: Yes, I do have admin rights on the server. No need for credential parameter